# What exactly is the difference between Chararray and Bytearray in Pig and/or Hive?

Tags: data-structures, hive, apache-pig

I assume in Java char[] and byte[] should be able to be converted seamlessly and treated as the same right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, pig *chararray* is internally represented by *java.lang.String* and pig *bytearray* is internally represented by *org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray* which is a wrapper around byte[] with some convenient methods. As for the seamless cast - see this table
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Cast+Operators
and examples below